# What is "sed -i 's,-m64,,g'" doing to this Makefile?

Tags: sed, make, gnu-make

What is the meaning of sed command `sed -i 's,-m64,,g' Makefile`?
Does it simply remove `-m64` argument from Makefile?
Is it the same with `sed -i 's/-m64//g' Makefile`, 
just use `/` delimiter in place of commas?

Comment: Also related: [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/92895) and [Using sed with special characters](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/137812)

Comment: Related from SO: [Using different delimiters in sed commands and range addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5864146/43452)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's the same as with `/` delimiter. Sometimes you may use different delimiters not to confuse `sed`.

In this case, you replace all `-m64` instances with empty string, not remove as such.

See [this resource](https://backreference.org/2010/02/20/using-different-delimiters-in-sed/) on using delimiters in `sed`.

Comment: what is the difference between replacing this data with empty string, and removing this data? Perhaps I'm missing something here.

Comment: in our terms, the same. with sed, a little different in terms of syntax. you replace with `s/pattern1/pattern2/g` and delete with `s/pattern/d`

Answer (score 4):

> Is it the same with `sed -i 's/-m64//g' Makefile`

Yes it is the same, any character can be used as the `sed` delimiter. You would usually do this when one of the strings contains the delimiter character, I don't know why the person who made that command decided to use a comma as a delimiter in this case.

Comment: personal preference? ;)

Comment: @Bart yes possibly I suppose, I was thinking it was a really arbitrary choice of character but I've just realised that commas are obviously used to separate arguments to functions in programming languages so that's probably why someone would choose it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use any delimiter you like.

Please see [this tutorial](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-2) for more info...

The -m64 will be replaced with nothing, so yes, it does remove it. Since you have a "g" at the end, this will be globally in the document.